# What to do with the revolute joint when simulating projectile motion?

Tags: libgdx, box2d

I am having a few problems I have set up my testing code for launching an arrow body, so I have attached an arrow body to a circle body by a revolute joint. and i have set up some basic testing code for launching the arrow body, but the problem is, is that the arrow body is stuck on the revolute joint, the arrow body  cannot escape this joint. I was wondering what a solution to this might be.

I use a button to launch the arrow, when the button is pressed the arrow moves. And also to solve the above problem I tried destroying the rotator body but it is not a good way of moving the arrow.

Any suggestions ?

Here is the code

```
revoluteJoint = new RevoluteJointDef();
    revoluteJoint.bodyA = rotatorBody;                          //defining the first body for the revolute joint 
    revoluteJoint.bodyB = arrowBody;                            //defining the second body for the revolute joint
    revoluteJoint.localAnchorB.set(0,0);                        //defining where you want the anchor point to be on the arrowbody
    revoluteJoint.collideConnected = false;                     //this is so that the relevant bodies can overlap
    revoluteJoint.enableMotor = true;                           //letting the joint move by itself
    revoluteJoint.maxMotorTorque = 250.0f;                      //maximum force
    revoluteJoint.motorSpeed = 0.0f;                            //speed is set to 0 so that the user can only move the arrow with touch
    world.createJoint(revoluteJoint);

buttonSTART.addListener(new InputListener(){
     @Override
     public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
             //game.setScreen(new Screenconfirmation(game));
        world.destroyBody(rotatorBody);
        arrowBody.setAwake(true);
        arrowBody.setGravityScale(1.0f);
        arrowBody.setAngularVelocity(0.0f);
        arrowBody.setTransform(arrowBody.getWorldPoint(new Vector2(3,0)), arrowBody.getAngle());
        arrowBody.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(150,0));
             return true;
     }
```

});

Comment: adding this line world.createBody(rotatorBodyDef); after world.destroybody seems to stop eclipse from crashing